# How is vcrpy importing from a parent directory in a test file

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, vcr

In the [vcrpy](https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy) github project, the [test file](https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy/blob/master/tests/integration/test_filter.py#L8) is referring a package [assertions](https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy/blob/master/tests/assertions.py) in a parent directory. I assume it should have referred it as `from ..assertions import ....` to refer it correctly.
Also, I don't see anywhere it is modifying the PYTHONPATH to make the path of `assertions.py` added directly to the PYTHONPATH. Not sure how this code is working? What is the magic happening to make it work?